# Django - importing form into template outside app

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an app with name account which contain all the models, views, and forms to be used in registering and signing in users. 
I have a template that is located outside the app folder that suppose to contain all the forms in account app. 
I am having problem trying to get the forms showing in the template.
Can someone help me?
Here are some snippet of codes:

## accounts/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Safe from injection, etc.
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password1', 'password2','first_name','last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

## accounts/view.py

```
from forms import UserRegistrationForm
def register_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    args = {}
    # prevent forgery
    args.update(csrf(request))

    # empty form
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('signup.html', args)

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('signup_success.html')
```

and finally the template, which is not in account folder. It's in the same folder as settings.py

## signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {{accounts.form.as_ul}}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

## UPDATE

Upon obtaining permission to move the template from the project manager, I moved it to accounts/template, and changed the render to response address.
I have new problem of form not submitting now.
OMG what's going on??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem lies on my signup.html file. It should have script for onclick and the form should have an id.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" id="form"> {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {{accounts.form.as_ul}}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="submit()">
</form>
<script>
    function submit() {document.forms["form"].submit();}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template should not be in the same directory as `settings.py`.

It should be in a directory within the accounts app: `accounts/templates/signup/html`.

If you've configured your Django project correctly then Django should pickup the template after restarting the web server.

Comment: I have moved the template to accounts/templates folder. <br> the forms are still not showing :/

Answer (score 0):

as I see you are passing `form` variable to template, 
but you are trying to use `accounts.form`.

Hope this helps.